# Embed Form from Planning Center to Wix

Tags: html, velo

We are trying to embed a form from Planning Center People to our Wix website. The code given is not compatible with Wix and we keep getting a "parsing error unexpected token" message.

Here are the instructions from the PCP website:

Step 1: Include the ChurchCenterModal script tag on your webpage in the  of your document:

Step 2: Add a link to your website (the location, name, and style is up to you):

" data-open-in-church-center-modal="true">Fill out our form!

Alternatively, if your website's content management system doesn't allow you to control the html of the link, you can also use a parameter in the URL itself:

?open-in-church-center-modal=true">Fill out our form!

Answer (score 0):

Bob:

I think you need to do two things on your Wix site.

1. You need to add the code that is required in the header section of your page

> Step 1: Include the ChurchCenterModal script tag on your webpage in
>   the  of your document:

You do this in your site dashboard->settings->tracking tools and analytics page. Just cut and paste the code in a head section after click Add Tool.

2. You need to use the alternate link method for getting the form

> Alternatively, if your website's content management system doesn't
>   allow you to control the html of the link, you can also use a
>   parameter in the URL itself:
>
> Give
>   online

To use this you should add a button on your page and create an onClick handler that calls [wix-fetch](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-fetch.html). Using the URL only not the rest of the HTML.

Should look something like this:

```
export function button1_click(event) {
    //Add your code for this event here:
    fetch("https://<your subdomain>.churchcenter.com/giving?open-in- 
       church-center-modal=true");
}
```

Hope that helps.
Steve